# Glide not loading SVG

Tags: android, kotlin, svg, android-glide

I want to display an image (type = SVG) that I receive via an API. For security reasons, authentication headers are necessary to get the image when loading.

This is my GlideModule:

```
@GlideModule
    @Excludes(OkHttpLibraryGlideModule.class)
    public class GlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    
        @Override
        public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
            Lazy<UserRepository> repository = inject(UserRepository.class);
            registry.register(SVG.class, PictureDrawable.class, new SvgDrawableTranscoder()).append(InputStream.class, SVG.class, new SvgDecoder());
    
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .readTimeout(15L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(15L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(new AuthInterceptor(repository.getValue()))
                    .build();
    
            registry.replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client));
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled() {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm using data binding to directly load the received image into the image view:

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("loadSvg")
fun loadSvgImage(view: ImageView, url: String?) {
   if (!url.isNullOrEmpty()) {
         val uri = Uri.parse(url)
         val requestBuilder = GlideApp.with(view)
            .`as`(PictureDrawable::class.java)
            .listener(SvgSoftwareLayerSetter())
         requestBuilder.load(uri).into(view)
   }
}
```

The image is not displayed, but there is also no warning/error message.

Is there something wrong with my GlideModule/Binding Function?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not supported, as Glide code indicates:

```
enum ImageType {
  GIF(true),
  JPEG(false),
  RAW(false),
  /** PNG type with alpha. */
  PNG_A(true),
  /** PNG type without alpha. */
  PNG(false),
  /** WebP type with alpha. */
  WEBP_A(true),
  /** WebP type without alpha. */
  WEBP(false),
  /** Unrecognized type. */
  UNKNOWN(false);
```

There is no SVG in the list.

However there is an app called PainterSVG which seems using Glide too, and I see most Glide features like place holder, center inside, thumbnail. I am not sure how they make it work with SVG.

Comment: No, Glide supports SVG. You can check it out in the official documentation (link provided by @Manikandan below)